# .attr('checked', true)Will Not Re-add on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `form` with a 'Reset' button.  When i select my `radio button` the data from my `DataTable` is passed and pre-pops my fields.  This working fine and does in fact pre-populate the relevant radio button

JQuery

```
if (modifyRecordData.startTime == 'Anytime') {
    $('#anyTimeRadioButton').attr('checked', true);
    $('#specificTimeRadioButton').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#startEndTimeFields').hide();
} else {
    $('#anyTimeRadioButton').removeAttr('checked');
    $('#specificTimeRadioButton').attr('checked', true);
    $('#startEndTimeFields').show();
    $('#startTimeHr').val(modifyRecordData.startTimeHr);
    $('#startTimeMin').val(modifyRecordData.startTimeMin);
    $('#endTimeHr').val(modifyRecordData.endTimeHr);
    $('#endTimeMin').val(modifyRecordData.endTimeMin);
}
```

**Data returned**

[image]

**Page loaded**
[image]

Now the issue, if the user, after data load goes to update the details and selects the other radio button the hidden fields are displayed (again correct)
[image]

Then user clicks the 'Reset' button and it fails in the correct `function`

```
$('#resetButton').mousedown(function (event) {
    buttonclicked = "Reset";
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    modifyRadioButtonSelection(modifyRecordData);
})
```

and then goes back to the initial loaded data and it does drop in the `IF` code above

Debuging
[image]

Then it re-hides the hidden section (which is correct) but it does not re-tick the `radio button` as expected.

[image]

If i dont have the following code in the `IF` it leaves the previously selected one checked although the data falls in the `IF`

```
$('#specificTimeRadioButton').removeAttr('checked');
```

No idea whats going wrong at all. I even tried adding the following the 'Reset' button `function` but it just will not re-check the correct `radio button

```
$('#anyTimeRadioButton').removeAttr('checked');
$('#specificTimeRadioButton').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: It may or may not be related to your issue but, unless you use a really ancient jQuery version, I suggest you switch to `.prop('checked', true)`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I tried `prop` soon as i posted as i completely forgot about it and guess what, it worked straight away. add it as an answer and i'll accept it.  I was just coming back to delete the post

Comment: Alright... That was a blind shot anyway xD Glad you got it sorted out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Historically, there's been a lot of ambiguity and confusion between three related but different concepts:

- The value of the HTML attribute in the source code.
- The value of the HTML attribute in DOM tree.
- The value of the JavaScript property.

To address that, jQuery/1.6.1 introduced the [`prop()` method](https://blog.jquery.com/2011/05/12/jquery-1-6-1-released/), which I suggest you adopt.